# How do I pass quotes in tectia ssh?

Tags: windows, command-line, ssh, windows-registry

We use windows OS but instead of using built in native ways to connect to remote machines, they installed tectia ssh.

So if I want to run commands on a remote machine I have to open cmd and do

`sshg3 server02`

I ssh into a computer. Once the session is connected I can natively put commands into the cmd and it'll execute on that machine I'm connected to.

Well one problem. I want to make it scripted. For simple commands all I have to do is

`sshg3 server05 "net user acc /active:yes"`

But one of the commands I frequently run is

`reg add "hklm\software\microsoft\windows nt\currentversion\winlogon" /v AutoAdminLogon /d 1 /f`

When I try to do `sshg3 server02 "reg add "hklm\software\microsoft\windows nt\currentversion\winlogon" /v AutoAdminLogon /d 1 /f "` it always returns "Invalid syntax see reg add /? for more info"

Because its not escaping the quotes so it thinks `reg add` is the only quoted thing.

I tried using backtick and I tried using ^ to escape the quotes. Cant figure out how to escape back ticks on here because it keeps showing 2 instead of one, so im using (backtick) instead

`sshg3 server02 "reg add ^"hklm\software\microsoft\windows nt\currentversion\winlogon^" /v AutoAdminLogon /d 1 /f"`

`sshg3 server02 "reg add (backtick)"hklm\software\microsoft\windows nt\currentversion\winlogon(backtick)" /v AutoAdminLogon /d 1 /f"`

Both commands return the same invalid syntax

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution.

Have to use double quotes around the reg key add part.